# Java regex ignore '.' symbol

Tags: java, regex, escaping, period

I'm trying to split a string at every '.' (period), but periods are a symbol used by java regexes. Example code,

```
String outstr = "Apis dubli hre. Agro duli demmos,".split(".");
```

I can't escape the period character, so how else do I get Java to ignore it?

Comment: I wonder how this compile. `split` returns an array. But to answer your question, you need to escape the `.`

Comment: You might also use `[.]` since the dot will lose it's (regex) meaning in a character class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***I can't escape the period character***, so how else do I get Java to ignore it?

You can escape the period character, but you must first consider how the string is interpreted.

In a Java string (that is fed to `Pattern.`[`compile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#compile%28java.lang.String%29)`(s)`)...

- `"."` is a regex meaning *any character*.
- `"\."` is an illegally-escaped string. This won't compile. As a regex in a *text editor*, however, this is perfectly legitimate, and means *a literal dot*.
- `"\\."` is a Java string that, *once interpreted*, becomes the regular expression `\.`, which is again the escaped (literal) dot.

What you want is

```
String outstr = "Apis dubli hre. Agro duli demmos,".split("\\.");
```

Comment: Hah, thanks. Java is kind of strange sometimes, with all it's layers.

Answer (score 5):

Use `"\\."` instead. Just using `.` means 'any character'.